# check datasource connection before transaction

Tags: java, glassfish, schedule

i am creating scheduller using java EE and glassfish, sometime task failed because connection time out.
is there any way to check data source connection before executing task, and delay task if connection failed?

```
@Schedule(minute = "*/30", hour = "*")
public void executeSceduler(String code, String name) {
     Product product= productFacade.find(code);
     product.setName(name);
     productFacade.edit(product);
    }
```

Comment: How about [isClosed()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isClosed()) method of Connection?

Comment: I avoid using manual connection because the connection is managed by Java EE, i was looking for a solution such as a method to ping connection pool, if there is.